# Libre Office - Linux DEB or RPM for Chrome OS?

Tags: package-management, libreoffice, chrome-book

I'm trying to install Libre Office on my Chromebook and I don't know whether to download the DEB or RPM version.

Comment: Apparently either one works. .deb seems to be more often referred to. See for example https://www.aboutchromebooks.com/news/how-to-install-linux-apps-on-a-chromebook-without-ever-touching-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Check this links for a solution that fits for you

**Download:** [Download LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download-libreoffice/)

> **On most Debian-based Linux distributions, users can double-click on .deb packages to install them**. This same functionality can now be found in the Chrome OS Canary and Dev channels. You can double-click on any .deb file in the Chrome OS Files app to start the installation process.
> [Chrome OS can now install Linux apps from .deb packages](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/08/08/chrome-os-canary-can-now-install-linux-apps-deb-packages/#:%7E:text=On%20most%20Debian-based%20Linux%20distributions%2C%20users%20can%20double-click,OS%20Files%20app%20to%20start%20the%20installation%20process.)

> Chromebooks are more powerful than you think. It’s no longer just a web browser anymore. It is also possible to run Linux programs, even Libre Office. **This guide will show you how to use Libre Office on your Chromebook**.
> [How to Use Libre Office on a Chromebook](https://www.addictivetips.com/chromebook/how-to-use-libre-office-on-a-chromebook/)

> Chromebooks
> [Libre Office | App Stores and Chromebooks](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-from-microsoft-and-mac-app-stores/)

> You can **get a LibreOffice-based app for Chromebooks from our
> certified developers** and ecosystem members:
> [Collabora Office ships for Chromebooks](https://www.collaboraoffice.com/press-releases/collabora-office-ships-for-chromebooks/)

> LibreOffice is not available for Chrome OS but there are some alternatives with similar functionality.
> [LibreOffice Alternatives for Chrome OS](https://alternativeto.net/software/libreoffice/?platform=chrome-os#:%7E:text=LibreOffice%20is%20not%20available%20for%20Chrome%20OS%20but,so%20hopefully%20you%20can%20find%20a%20suitable%20replacement.)

Answer (score 0):

Neither will help you. ChromeOS is not a debian and not a red hat descendant, and you will need to go through the official app store unless you have modified your installation (which I'm sure you would have mentioned).

Comment: Actually looks like it's been possible since at least -20.